# How can I render a React component from server.js to App.js using post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm a beginner in React and Javascript so still learning :)

I'm creating a magic 8 ball application where once the Button is clicked, using the post method, I want to return a random answer (one of the 20 in my server.js) back to the same App.js file... I assume as a response?

How can I render an HTML element (i.e. `answers[number]`) back to my App.js where my **Answer** paragraph is?

Sidenote: I've tried using `res.send()` to set it up - is this along the right lines?

I am using node.js and express as the server.

EDIT: full server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({dev})
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare()
.then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.get('/p/:id', (req, res) => {
    const actualPage = '/post'
    const queryParams = { title: req.params.id }
    app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
  })

  server.get('*', (req,res) => {
    return handle(req,res)
  })

  server.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
  })

  /* Return random answer after question is submitted.*/
  server.post('/', (req,res) => {
    const answers = [
      "It is certain.",
      "It is decidedly so.",
      "Without a doubt.",
      "Yes - definitely.",
      "You may rely on it.",
      "As I see it, yes.",
      "Most likely.",
      "Outlook good.",
      "Yes.",
      "Signs point to yes.",
      "Reply hazy, try again.",
      "Ask again later.",
      "Better not tell you now.",
      "Cannot predict now.",
      "Concentrate and ask again.",
      "Don't count on it.",
      "My reply is no.",
      "My sources say no.",
      "Outlook not so good.",
      "Very doubtful.",
      "Computer says no."
    ]
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random()*21);
    console.log("Raw answer: ");
    console.log(answers[number]);
    res.status(200).send(answers[number]);
    console.log("Response: ");
    console.log(res);
  })

})
.catch((ex) => {
  console.error(ex.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

EDIT: full App.js:

```
import Layout from '../components/MyLayout.js'
import Header from '../components/Header.js'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { Component } from "react";
import { spring } from 'popmotion';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      response: undefined
    };
    this.incrementCounter = this.incrementCounter.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      count: parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count")) || 0
    });
  }

  incrementCounter() {
    const count = this.state.count + 1;
    localStorage.setItem("count", count);
    this.setState({
      count: count
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('/', { method: 'POST' }).then(response => this.setState({response}));
    console.log("this.state.response:");
    console.log(this.state.response);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <main>
          <Header />
            <div style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
              <h1 style={{ fontFamily:"Arial", fontSize:"50px" }}>Magic 8 Ball</h1>
            </div>

            <div style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
              <form className="question-input" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <TextField
                  id="inputquestion"
                  autoComplete="off"
                  placeholder="Ask your question..."
                  margin="normal"
                />
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  type="submit"
                  color="primary"
                  onClick={this.incrementCounter.bind(this)}
                  id="submitquestion"
                  style={{ width: "100px", fontSize:17 }}>Shake Me!
                </Button>
              </form>
            </div>

            <div style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
              <p>Answer: </p>
              <p>Question count: {this.state.count}</p>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of stuff is well explained in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Everytime you do an API request you need to use state because it is a side-effect. I suggest you read the docs and understand it, but to make it work in your component add this at the beginning of your component:

```
class BlaBla extends Component {
    state = {
        response: undefined
    };

    /* Rest of component code */
}
```

And change your fetch request to look like this:

```
fetch('/', { method: 'POST' }).then(response => this.setState({response}));
```

By adding state, you're also going to have problems with binding so change your method declaration to an arrow function, from this:

```
handleSubmit(event) { /* code */ }
```

to this:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => { /* code */ }
```

To display the result in your answer paragraph do this:

```
<p> Answer: {this.state.response} </p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Making sense.. Tried this but got error. The response goes through according to inspecting the Network.

`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Response]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: Your server is responding with a JSON object probably, instead of a plain text string.  You probably have to print out {this.state.response.body}
If that doesn't work, log the response to the console and check how the object looks, then use the property with the string you want to see.

Comment: Weirdly the object returns just as the string in the console, e.g. 'It is certain.' Which is why I'm confused it's returning a JSON.

Comment: Which one is printing a string? this.state.response?

Comment: Okay slowly getting there! Seems the response isn't actually capturing the string itself. Printed `this.state.response` which came out as `undefined`. I did `console.log(res);` and a large JSON was printed out, no objects of which were the string. How do I assign the random string to a part of the response?

Comment: Your server.js is ok, what you see when you log "res" is a full express response which is not what you should be interested in. Your client is the problem. I'm having trouble keeping up with what you did so maybe edit the answer or put a codepen up so I can see where you are. I'd recommend we start a chat, I don't think I can help you fully with only comments. Anyways, at the moment, if you only did what my answers says then try putting a console.log(this.state.response) in your render method, and let me know what it prints. Remember that it should print at least twice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189984/discussion-between-calvin2011-and-dohn).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to save the result of the fetch call to your component state. Using setState, it will automatically trigger a rerender of your component and display the new answer.

Try this:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // assuming the fetch works ok...
    fetch('/', { method: 'POST' }).then(response => 
      response.json().then(data => this.setState({answer:response}) )
     )
  }
```

then inside render():

```
<div style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
  <p>Answer:{this.state.answer}</p>
  <p>Question count: {this.state.count}</p>
</div>
```

EDIT:

You may need to parse the response as json e.g.

```
fetch('/', { method: 'POST' }).then(response => 
  this.setState({answer:JSON.parse(response)})
)
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense, however, getting this error when I try it: `Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0` Any ideas? Because it's a JSON object returning somehow?

Comment: when you console.log the results what did you get? I've made an edit which may work in your case.

Comment: Weirdly, I get the result of the random string itself e.g. 'It is certain.', no JSON object. Tried the JSON.parse but same error again, just a different token this time? `Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: ah then no need for parsing you can just do setState({answer:response})